# FISH - How to hide hostname/computer from prompt?

Tags: prompt, fish

For context, I am using FISH 3.1.0.

I looked in `fish_config`, but none of the prompt options just remove the hostname/computer while keeping the rest the same.

Is there a way to keep most of the default prompt, but just remove that part at the beginning?

I'm just using the default prompt. Here it is in full using `type fish_prompt`:

```
fish_prompt is a function with definition
# Defined in /usr/share/fish/functions/fish_prompt.fish @ line 4
function fish_prompt --description 'Write out the prompt'
    set -l last_pipestatus $pipestatus
    set -l normal (set_color normal)

    # Color the prompt differently when we're root
    set -l color_cwd $fish_color_cwd
    set -l prefix
    set -l suffix '>'
    if contains -- $USER root toor
        if set -q fish_color_cwd_root
            set color_cwd $fish_color_cwd_root
        end
        set suffix '#'
    end

    # If we're running via SSH, change the host color.
    set -l color_host $fish_color_host
    if set -q SSH_TTY
        set color_host $fish_color_host_remote
    end

    # Write pipestatus
    set -l prompt_status (__fish_print_pipestatus " [" "]" "|" (set_color 
    $fish_color_status) (set_color --bold $fish_color_status) $last_pipestatus)

    echo -n -s (set_color $fish_color_user) "$USER" $normal @ (set_color 
    $color_host) (prompt_hostname) $normal ' ' (set_color $color_cwd) 
(prompt_pwd) $normal (fish_vcs_prompt) $normal $prompt_status $suffix " "                       
end
```

Comment: Show us your prompt: `type fish_prompt`

Comment: Unfortunately copy/paste mangles it quite badly. It will take some time to fix for posting. EDIT: Done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `funced fish_prompt`
2. on the last `echo` line, remove the stuff you want to remove. Save and exit your editor
3. you may be prompted to save the function, do so. If you don't get prompted, do `funcsave fish_prompt`

Comment: I'm not even sure what editor this is. It doesn't appear to be nano or vi/vim. How do I exit? EDIT: Enter seems to exit. Not sure how you'd add new lines then.

Comment: Specifically, the echo line now reads:

echo -n -s (set_color $fish_color_user) (set_color $color_cwd) 
(prompt_pwd) $normal (fish_vcs_prompt) $normal $prompt_status $suffix " "

Comment: Read the docs for `funced`: https://fishshell.com/docs/current/cmds/funced.html -- set your favourite editor in the env var VISUAL or EDITOR

Comment: There is a problem - the change does not stick around after the session is over. A new shell window will have the old prompt back.

Comment: Doing ```funcsave fish_prompt``` after exiting the editor fixed it.